# NetLogo: patches to display number of turtles on the patch

Tags: netlogo

I'd like to have each patch display the number of turtles located in that patch.  I know I need to use the plabel command, but I cannot figure out how to tell the patch to display the sum of turtles occupying it.  Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that easily by "count turtles-here"

```
to setup
  Clear-all
  Create-turtles 50 [move-to patch random 30 random 30]

  reset-ticks
end


to set-label

  ask patches [
    ifelse count turtles-here > 0 
    [set plabel count turtles-here]
    [set plabel ""]
  ]

end

to go
  ask turtles
  [rt random 5
    fd 0.3]
  set-label
  tick
end
```

I have included a working example, but your answer is "`set plabel count turtles-here`"